# Goodness of fit for a multi-level model

Tags: bayesian, maximum-likelihood, goodness-of-fit, gaussian-process

I'm currently trying to figure out how to properly express a 'goodness of fit' criteria for a Bayesian model that has several steps. I have a 2 dimension dataset of position values (x and y) and parameter values at those positions. I first fit a radial profile with just a straight line (emcee), and then the azimuthal variation with a Gaussian Process Regression (scikit-learn).

I can calculate the BIC for the straight line fit, and pull the marginal log-likelihood out of the GPR, but it's unclear to me how I can combine them for an overall goodness of fit. Any suggestions here would be much appreciated! Alternatively, if someone can point towards scikit-learn to include this 1-dimension radial term in the fit, that may also solve my problems, but I don't think this is possible.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: first of all, if I've understood correctly, this isn't a multi-level model, more of a boosted model. Have you tried calculating the test $R^2$ as a starting point?

Comment: @gazza89 The $R^2$ seems like a great way to go -- what I really want to show is that adding the azimuthal contribution provides a better representation of the data, so this seems ideal

Comment: got it. Yes, measuring $R^{2}$ on a test set is the way I would go (or a related metric such as MAE if you're expecting a few outliers you don't want to over-penalise). You could also compare BIC of the unboosted model to BIC of the boosted model, as another test.